# char pointer and printf

Tags: c, pointers, printf

Hi please advise me on the following output:

```
main()
{
  char ***x = "jjhljlhjlhjl";
  char **q = *x;

  printf("x:%s\n",x);
  printf("q:%s\n",&q);    

}

Output:
x:jjhljlhjlhjl
q:jjhl
```

Why is q doesn't print the whole of x ?

Comment: It's `int main()`, btw.

Comment: Actually, K&R C allows for function declarations without types (the `int` is implied)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program invokes undefined behavior, so there are not really any limitations on what it may output.

```
  char ***x = "jjhljlhjlhjl";
```

Although `x` is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer, it is assigned the address of a string literal.

```
  char **q = *x;
```

`q` is a pointer to a pointer, and is assigned the result of dereferencing `x`. Since `x` is actually pointing to an object of incompatible type, the result of derferencing it is undefined.

If we pretend like this is supposed to work, then `*x` is now a pointer to a pointer, and so it might treat the `sizeof(char **)` bytes of the string literal as if it were an address and assign that value to `q`.

```
  printf("x:%s\n",x);
```

Since `x` is a pointer, that pointer value is passed to `printf()`. Since the `%s` is provided, the pointer value is treated like a string. Since `x` was assigned the address of a string literal, that string is what gets printed.

```
  printf("q:%s\n",&q);
```

The address of `q` is passed to `printf()`. Since the `%s` is provided, the pointer value is treated like a string. However, derferencing the contents of that pointer is actually `sizeof(char **)` bytes of the string literal. There is no guarantee that the bytes read will be properly `NUL` terminated, so it is just happenstance that something got printed at all.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the string `"jjhljlhjlhjl"` is only a `char *`, whereas you assign it to a `char ***`. When you print `x`, it gets interpreted as a `char *` by `printf`, which winds up being the correct string.

As for printing `&q` as a string address, you're effectively printing the contents of `q`. When you dereference `x`, you get a `char **`, which in your case, is 4 bytes. But because `x` actually points to text data, `*x` will grab the first four bytes (i.e. characters) of your string. The fact that it's printing **only** four characters is pure chance.